# How I predict a response with NA using logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, missing-data

I have this data set:

age -- job ------- loan -- y
57 -- retired - - -  yes -- no
44 -- admin - - --   no -- no
39 -- unknown --   no --  no
47 -- services --  no -- yes
41 -- admin  -----    no -- NA
51 -- teacher  ---  yes --no
45 -- unknown -- no -- yes
57 -- retired ------   no -- no
42 -- teacher -----   no  --NA
30 -- student -----   no -- NA

I want to predict all the values of y by using logistic regression, but I get only 7 out of 10 predictions. So, it omits the cases with `y==NA`.

Here is my codes:

```
 fit <- glm(y~ age+ as.factor(job)+ as.factor(loan), data= mydat, family=binomial)     
 predict( fit, type="response", na.action=na.pass)
```

How I can predict the response value `y` even in cases with missing values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing because you either want a mulinomial logit/probit model, where NA is a third category of outcome or you want an imputation model to fill-in values of `y` based on the other data. As @Roland has answered, you're not going to be able to predict missing values using a binary outcome model provided by `glm`.

If the former (multinomial logit/probit model), take a look at your options [on the Econometrics Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Econometrics.html).

If the latter (imputation), you also have lots of options like [Amelia](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/index.html), [mice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html), and [mi](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mi/index.html).

Comment: Thank you Thomas, yes I actually try to impute the NA values by using logistic regression. I have already used mice package, but what I try to do here is to get a new data set with the imputed values; because I couldn't get it using mice. Do you have an idea about that?

Comment: Check out Amelia, which will give you a list containing several imputed dataframes. It's very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have data for something, you cannot model it and consequently not predict. E.g., you have no data for students with no loans. So how do you suggest to predict y for students with no loans? That would require magic.

On the other hand, if you omit the job from your model or recode somehow (e.g., beginner/experienced/unknown) you could be able to predict all cases. The best advice would of course be to get more data.

Comment: Thank you Roland, I thought it's possible to predict the response (even if it's a missing value)if we have all the values of explanatory variables along with their parameters.

Comment: But for each combination of predictor factor variables you need at least some response values. Otherwise the information is simply not there.

Answer (score 0):

Delete "student" from your data and use the newdata argument in predict:

```
predict(fit,newdata=mydat,type="response")
```